# Which way of real-time drawing is better?

Tags: swift, macos

I am making a program that simulates some physical interaction between particles and draws their trails. My current solution is using NSView descendant that has override DrawRect, but it seems like not the best solution for some reason, one being not very high FPS when drawing many objects. Is there any better way like OpenGL, or is it "as good as it gets", and performance boost is little to none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If UI content changes all time, then OpenGL is definitely correct approach. The idea behind it is that screen refreshes at constant frame rate (ex. 60FPS) and you can draw different picture each frame. Traditional Cocoa views are designed to keep static picture.

There are many frameworks that give you high-level API for drawing, so you deal with view-like sprites and textures, and you are free from OpenGL-specific functions and states. I have experience with [Cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/) and would recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to use OpenGL with no frameworks, where to look first for reference?